# Sharing to Stories on Facebook

Tags: android, bitmap, facebook-share, android-sharing, instagram-story

I am sharing image stories to Facebook using "Sharing to Stories for Android Developer" and Getting error when i am sharing image :

Error : facebook cannot access this media at the moment. please try again later (last image please check)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/sharing-to-stories/android-developers

add dependencies
`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:15.1.0'`
`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:15.1.0'`

Manifest file:
[image]

MainActivity: pickImage from gallery on ClickButton using function.
[image]

MainActivity: onActivityResult function.
[image]

MainActivity: getImageUri
[image]

MainActivity: shareData function.
[image]

Result: In bottom of image as Toast.
[image]

Kindly help me out!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this:

pass the Uri from onActivityResult like this: shareData(**selectedImageUri**);
and use in shareData modified line this: intent.setDataAndType(**uri**, "image/jpeg");

If any queries regarding sharing posts/stories/feeds on facebook/instagram/tweeter ping me.